# Maximize and minimize a function using Lagrange multipliers.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I want to maximize and minimize $$h(a,b) = a + b$$ given the constraint $$g(a,b) = a^{\frac{1}{3}}b^{\frac{2}{3}} = l$$

I'm trying to use Lagrange multipliers. Here's what I did:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial a} = \lambda \frac{\partial h}{\partial a} \implies 1 = \lambda(\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{a^{\frac{2}{3}}}b^{\frac{2}{3}})\\\\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial b} = \lambda \frac{\partial h}{\partial b} \implies 1 = \lambda(\frac{2}{3}a^{\frac{1}{3}}\frac{1}{b^{\frac{1}{3}}})\\
\end{align}

Then I solved the second equation for $b$:

\begin{align}
(b^{\frac{1}{3}})^3 &= (\frac{2}{3} \lambda a^{\frac{1}{3}})^3\\
b &= \frac{8}{27} \lambda^3 a
\end{align}

Plugged this value for $b$ into the constraint equation and solved for $a$:

\begin{align}
a^{\frac{1}{3}}b^{\frac{2}{3}} &= l\\
a^{\frac{1}{3}}(\frac{8}{27} \lambda^3 a)^{\frac{2}{3}} &= l\\
a^{\frac{1}{3}}(\frac{2}{3} \lambda a^{\frac{1}{3}})^2 &= l\\
a^{\frac{1}{3}}(\frac{4}{9} \lambda^2 a^{\frac{2}{3}}) &= l\\
\frac{4}{9} \lambda^2 a &= l\\
a &= \frac{9}{4} \frac{l}{\lambda^2}
\end{align}

Then I took this value for $a$ and plugged it into the expression I obtained for $b$ to get:

\begin{align}
b &= \frac{8}{27} \lambda^3 a\\
b &= \frac{8}{27} \lambda^3 (\frac{9}{4}\frac{l}{\lambda^2})\\
b &= \frac{2}{3} \lambda l
\end{align}

So now I have:

\begin{align}
a &= \frac{9}{4} \frac{l}{\lambda^2} \\
b &= \frac{2}{3} \lambda l \\
a^{\frac{1}{3}}b^{\frac{2}{3}} &= l
\end{align}

But now I'm stuck. And I'm not sure I am correct so far.

Comment: you miss $2ab=1$

Comment: another approach is $(2ab^2)^{\frac{1}{3}} \le \frac{2a+b+b}{3}$ when $a,b>0$.

Comment: Where does $2ab = 1$ come from?

Comment: $\lambda(\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{a^{\frac{2}{3}}}b^{\frac{2}{3}})=\lambda(\frac{2}{3}a^{\frac{1}{3}}\frac{1}{b^{\frac{1}{3}}})$